# PHP constants conflict in different packages

Tags: php, path, autoload

Im working on an agile PHP project separated into several libraries and plugins and autoloaded with composer. the problem that i run into is that i have nearly the same config file for each library like so:

```
<?php

 define('ROOT', __DIR__); // root dir
 define('APP', ROOT . DS . 'app'); // app directory
```

Something like this in all my packages which is creating constants conflict.

So how can i do something cleaner in which each package will have its own **paths** and **links** without having any conflict with other packages as well with composer packages thanks.

Comment: Use namespaces for this.

Comment: I am using  namespaces for classes  but for constants i don't think i would be useful because the config file should be loaded first  ? I am getting it wrong ?

Comment: If the answer helped, please be sure to accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply solve this problem by using, [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.rationale.php) and [class constants](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.constants.php).

For example:

LibA:

```
<?php 

namespace libraryA;

class Config
{
    const ROOT = __DIR__;
    const DS = '/';
    const APP = self::ROOT . self::DS . 'appA';
}
```

LibB:

```
<?php 

namespace libraryB;

class Config
{
    const ROOT = __DIR__;
    const DS = '/';
    const APP = self::ROOT . self::DS . 'appB';
}
```

Which you can access easily anywhere like this:

```
<?php

use libraryA\Config as AConfig;
use libraryB\Config as BConfig;


var_dump(AConfig::APP, BConfig::APP);
```

This way they will remain separate and and the code will be more readable.
This is just an example, you don't really have to re declare `DS` and `ROOT` for every config class. you can just use 1 parent class to contain these global constants.

Comment: This seems quite helpful but what if i have `const ROOT = dirname(__DIR__, 5)` ?

Comment: @jimyrazit You don't necessarily have to use constants for this, you can instead use methods and properties and use the config classes as objects.

Comment: any idea how laravel or modern frameworks setup there config staff ? since they all have the same logic of separate packages

Comment: Every framework has their own method, some uses `YAML` some `ini` some convert an `array` into `objects` etc.

Comment: Thank you so much ! that makes lot of sense . appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

There are actually three types of user-defined constant in PHP:

- Global constants declared with `define()`, which have the same value in all scopes. These should be used with care, because as you've discovered, it's easy to end up with two pieces of code trying to define the same constant. You can however check if the constant already exists, if you're sure it's being used for the same purpose in both places e.g. `if ( ! defined('MAGIC') ) { define('MAGIC', 'xyzzy'); }`
- Class constants, declared with `const` inside a class definition, and accessed with the syntax `ClassName::FOO`. These are more explicitly scoped, and since the class can be autoloaded, you don't need to explicitly `include` a file with the definitions. The class can in turn be in a namespace, for additional separation between packages. However, there are limits on what you can define them based on, e.g. they can't be the result of a function call, unlike with `define()`.
- Namespace constants, declared with `const` in a file which has a `namespace` declaration at the top. These can be referenced either with a fully-qualified name like `Foo\Bar\MAGIC`, or [aliased in a particular file to a shorter name](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php), using `use const Foo\Bar\MAGIC` or `use const Foo\Bar\MAGIC as BAR_MAGIC`. They save you having to create an otherwise empty class just to put your constants in, but unfortunately can't be autoloaded, so you still need to explicitly `include` a file to define them.